# Comparacion entre dos tablas sql

Tags: base-de-datos, sql, tablas

bueno necesito ayuda con mi código de sql.
Este es mi código:

```
SELECT Pedidos.Numero, Pedidos.Estado, Pedidositems.Cantidad AS CantidadPedida, RemitosItems.Cantidad AS CantidadEntregada, pedidositems.Codigo AS CodigodeProducto, pedidositems.Descripción AS DescripcionProducto

FROM (((((Empresas
LEFT JOIN `productos` ON (`productos`.`recid`=`pedidositems`.`idproducto`))
INNER JOIN `pedidositems` ON (`pedidositems`.`idpedido`=`pedidos`.`recid`)) 
INNER JOIN `pedidos` ON (`pedidos`.`idref`=`contactos`.`idcontacto`) AND pedidos.estado = 0)
LEFT JOIN remitositems ON (`remitositems`.`idpedprod`=`pedidositems`.`recid`))
LEFT JOIN remitos ON (remitos.RecID=remitositems.IDRemito) AND remitos.estado =1)
```

Este es el resultado para una de las tantas empresas

[image: Este es el resultado para una de las tantas empresas]

Básicamente lo que necesitaría, es que todos esos productos que ya están entregados completamente, desaparezcan. Que me queden los productos como el segundo ítem, o  también productos entregados parcialmente si los hubiese en el pedido. Yo pensaba poner algún tipo de relación entre las Cantidades de Los pedidos y de los Remitos, Si son diferentes o algo de eso, pero cuando lo intenté me filtraba mal los datos.

Bueno ese era mi inconveniente, espero alguien me pueda ayudar. Muchas gracias

Comment: como sabes cuando el producto ya esta entregado (los que muestras ya estan entregas segun lo que dices)? no logro asimilar bien los resultados que muestras.

Comment: cuando la cantidadEntregada es 0 es porque aun no esta entregado? así filtrarías tu query?

Comment: Hola francisco, en esa consulta hay Pedidos tanto por Remitados por parte, Como sin remitar. (En el inner join de pedidos, al final puse que solo me traiga los que tienen estado 0, ese estado quiere decir que estén Pendientes)
Esta mostrado de esa forma porque ami me interesa ver los productos que le debo a cada empresa según el pedido que haya echo cada una.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que no has compartido la estructura de tus tablas, pero en base a los alias de tu select podría decir que tu solución es la siguiente; debes usar un **where** en el cual indiques que la cantidad entregada sea menor a la solicitada, así excluirías a los que han sido entregados completamente:

```
WHERE Pedidositems.Cantidad > RemitosItems.Cantidad
```

Agrega esa condición y listo. Saludos.

Comment: Hola Rostan gracias por tu respuesta, Había probado agregarle eso pero de Tener un promedio por decirte de 1000 Pedidos, Con esa restricción solo me aparecen 100 o 200. No hay forma de lea todos los registros igual, pero al momento de mostrarlos muestre con esa condición?

Comment: Es que va a obedecer al filtro, podrías compartir un ejemplo, para ayudarte.

Comment: Bueno, yo mas arriba publique un ejemplo de esa Empresa A con ese codigo y ahora al poner esa restricción ya no está mas por ejemplo.
Que clase de ejemplo te resultaría mejor para que me puedas ayudar?

Comment: De ser el ejemplo la Empresa A debería salir, pero solo con el producto de código dp0002 ya que tiene pendientes, seguro que no se muestra?

Answer (score 0):

Si estoy seguro, ya por el hecho de que Sin esa reestricción hay muchos pedidos con productos sin entregar, y una vez aplicada esa reestriccion solo aparecen las Cantidades distintas pero no las que tienen 0.
Muestro ejemplo Rostan:
Sin el Where:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el Where:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podes ver las que tienen cantidades entregadas 0, también desaparecen

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entendi, solo deseas mostrar los que aun no han sido entregados:

**SOL**  (con su sintaxis)

```
                SELECT Pedidos.Numero, Pedidos.Estado, Pedidositems.Cantidad AS CantidadPedida, RemitosItems.Cantidad AS CantidadEntregada, pedidositems.Codigo AS CodigodeProducto, pedidositems.Descripción AS DescripcionProducto

                FROM (((((Empresas
                LEFT JOIN `productos` ON (`productos`.`recid`=`pedidositems`.`idproducto`))
                INNER JOIN `pedidositems` ON (`pedidositems`.`idpedido`=`pedidos`.`recid`)) 
                INNER JOIN `pedidos` ON (`pedidos`.`idref`=`contactos`.`idcontacto`) AND pedidos.estado = 0)
                LEFT JOIN remitositems ON (`remitositems`.`idpedprod`=`pedidositems`.`recid`) )
                LEFT JOIN remitos ON (remitos.RecID=remitositems.IDRemito) AND remitos.estado =1) where Pedidositems.Cantidad > RemitosItems.Cantidad OR RemitosItems.Cantidad IS NULL
```

Comment: Hola francisco, Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Creo que encontré la solución pero se relaciona con tu respuesta también, lo que hice fue al final agregarle esto:
` WHERE Pedidositems.Cantidad > RemitosItems.Cantidad OR RemitosItems.Cantidad IS NULL `
Yo tenia el where solamente con que la cantidad de pedidos tiene que ser mayor a la de remitos, Entonces le agregue que tambien me contabilice los nulos y al parecer funciono! Muchas Gracias!

Comment: ok estimado, de nada ;) si la respuesta de arriba cumple no olvides marcar, saludos ;)